# jQuery hide div, show div with new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, hide, show

I am trying to retract my div, then show it with new content based on which link they clicked.

HTML:

```
          <div id="menu">
    <ul>
                <a href="#" title="content_1" alt="about" class="menu"><li>about</li></a>
                <a href="#" title="content_2" alt="contact" class="menu"><li>contact</li></a>
                <a href="#" title="content_3" alt="cv" class="menu"><li>cv</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>

       <div class="content">
            test
        <div id="content_1" class="content">
            content1
        </div>
        <div id="content_2" class="content">
            content2
        </div>
        <div id="content_3" class="content">
            content3
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a.menu").click(function() {
                var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
                $(".content").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
                $("#"+clicked).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
position: absolute;

left:303px;
top: 200px;
width: 100%;

margin-top: 200px;
background: #6c7373;

 }

#content_1, #content_2, #content_3 {
display: none;
 }
```

What happens is: the div retracts, but does not reappear at all, what is going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the menu? My suspicion is that the title doesn't match the content id.

Comment: added to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the outer `.content` to `.content-wrapper`.

Comment: That fixed it - but why? Also, how do I get content_1 to appear on page load?

Comment: The outer div was being hidden (because it had the same class) and then never shown again.

Comment: You can show #content_1 on page load using the same code: `$("#content_1").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that the container for all of the potential DIVs has the `content` class so it's being hidden as well. Since the container is hidden, it won't matter if you "show" one of the contained elements.  Second, note that the "hide" statement and the "show" statement will have a race condition since they will both apply to the element that's being hidden. It would be better to show the item in the callback to the hide operation or exclude it from being hidden.

```
<div class="content_wrapper"> <!-- give it a different class -->
        test
    <div id="content_1" class="content">
        content1
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="content">
        content2
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" class="content">
        content3
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.menu").click(function() {
            var clickedID = '#' + $(this).attr('title');
            $(".content:not(" + clickedID +")").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
            $(clickedID).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that confusion. Understand it a lot better now.

Answer (score 1):

Show and hide are both working at the same time. To avoid the conflict (and not hide then show the content that's visible if the user clicks the same item twice), show the one you want and hide the others by selecting them using `siblings()`

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deLb8/1/)

```
$("a.menu").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#"+clicked).show(1000).siblings().hide(1000);
});
```

This will also solve the problem you have that you have given the wrapper div the class of .content too.

Also your ul li structure is wrong. You need the a tags inside the li. li must come directly after ul.

Comment: Thank you, your solution did not work but I have amended by li tags. Thanks!

Comment: It says a lot more about the rest of my poor code not working along side it than it does about yours, don't worry!